# Covert to the excel using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel

```
data = {
  'name_1': {
    '2022-05-13': 48,
    '2022-03-14': 17,
    '2022-03-15': 16,

  },
  'name_2': {
    '2022-05-13': 36,
    '2022-05-14': 20,
    '2022-05-16': 15,

  },
  'name_3': {
    '2022-05-13': 12,
    '2022-05-14': 15,
    '2022-05-12': 20,

  },
  'name_4': {
    '2022-05-11': 1,
    '2022-05-12': 14
  },
  'name_5': {
    '2022-05-13': 14,
    '2022-03-15': 16,

  }
}
```

Convert this to excel file to by giving the date range input

Example giving range between 2022-05-13 to 2022-03-15

[the data should shows like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiaFD.png)

Comment: Maybe you can check [here](https://www.marsja.se/how-to-convert-json-to-excel-python-pandas/)

Comment: Tried @Wtow but the column is not sort. I need the date to sorted in column

Comment: Try to use `data.sort_index()`

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`pandas`](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/)

```py
import pandas as pd


df = (pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')
      .fillna(0)
      .sort_index(axis=0)
      .sort_index(axis=1))

df.to_excel('output.xlsx')
```

```
print(df)

        2022-03-14  2022-03-15  2022-05-11  2022-05-12  2022-05-13  2022-05-14  2022-05-16
name_1        17.0        16.0         0.0         0.0        48.0         0.0         0.0
name_2         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0        36.0        20.0        15.0
name_3         0.0         0.0         0.0        20.0        12.0        15.0         0.0
name_4         0.0         0.0         1.0        14.0         0.0         0.0         0.0
name_5         0.0        16.0         0.0         0.0        14.0         0.0         0.0
```